# Lumia 1320 won't turn on after downgrading

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-1320

I updated my Lumia 1320 to Windows 10 Mobile preview, and after that I tried to downgrade back to Windows Phone 8.1 using the Windows Device Recovery tool, but that was unsuccessful.

After that my phone now doesn't turn on (not even showing Nokia logo that shows on boot up). It only vibrates when I connect it to a PC or charger, or when I press and hold power button. What's the problem? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Hard reset instructions for Lumia 1320:

1. Turn your Lumia 1320 off. Make sure your battery is charged at least 50%.
2. Press **Volume DOWN** and keep pressing it while you **connect the charger until you see an exclamation mark**!.
3. Press - **in this order** - **Volume UP** - **Volume DOWN** - **POWER** - **VOLUME DOWN**.
4. Your phone will reset and reboot. Pls be patient during the reset process.

[Source](http://www.hard-reset.com/nokia-lumia-1320-hard-reset.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your Phone is dead but try to do Hard Reset, i hope that it will help you